# C++ countof Implementation for Member Arrays

Tags: c++, templates, g++, c++14

I am attempting to create the equivalent of the Visual Studio _countof macro using C++ templates.  The following are my proposed definitions:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
inline constexpr size_t countof(T const (&array)[N]) {
    return N;
}
template<typename T, typename U, size_t N>
inline constexpr size_t countof(T const (U::&array)[N]) {
    return N;
}
```

The second declaration above was an attempt to fix the following code, which generates a compile-time error in g++ 9 with the message: "error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘foo::bar’":

```
struct foo {
    int const bar[4];
    static_assert(countof(bar) == 4);
};
```

However, when I add the second definition, and change the assertion to use `foo::bar`, g++ generates the error: "error: ‘template constexpr const size_t countof’ conflicts with a previous declaration".

I can change the code to use pointer-to-member (instead of reference to member), but that seems like it should be unnecessary.  Does anyone know of a way to make a version of `countof` that only compiles when passed an array, and works in a reasonable way for both free and member variable arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the usage of `bar` is invalid in `static_assert(countof(bar) == 4);`, you need an instance of `foo` and get the member array `bar` to pass to `countof`.

> I can change the code to use pointer-to-member (instead of reference to member), but that seems like it should be unnecessary.

You can change the code to use pointer-to-member. e.g.

```
template<typename T, typename U, size_t N>
inline constexpr size_t countof(T const (U::*array)[N]) {
    return N;
}
```

then

```
static_assert(countof(&foo::bar) == 4);
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1aF0JqmVwP8bDXAW)

Or change `countof` to specify the type instead of passing the array to it.

```
template<typename T>
struct count_of{};
template<typename T, size_t N>
struct count_of<T const [N]> {
    constexpr static size_t value = N;
};
template<typename T>
inline constexpr size_t countof() {
    return count_of<T>::value;
}
```

then

```
static_assert(countof<decltype(foo::bar)>() == 4);
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/cfxfehf89UZgk70m)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out a way to do this without macros, but [this](http://cnicholson.net/2011/01/stupid-c-tricks-a-better-sizeof_arra) post provides a way to get both type-safety (ensuring the argument passed to countof is an array) and supports both free and member arrays.  The resulting code is:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
char (&COUNTOF_REQUIRES_ARRAY_ARGUMENT(T (&array)[N]))[N];

#define countof(x) sizeof(COUNTOF_REQUIRES_ARRAY_ARGUMENT(x))
```